# Escaping special characters in Unix shell

Tags: shell, unix, quoting

it is said that " " , ' ' , \ escape the special characters a.k.a their special meaning , but when i do something like this

```
date +"Today is \%A"
```

it wont write "Today is %A" but it writes same result as there wasnt "\" = "Today is thurstday". Why is this happening? I thought i understood how escaping characters in unix works but this confuses me quite a lot

Im typing it into terminal  im on /bin/bash/ (thats what $SHELL outputs) , the strange thing is , that if \ does not escape char in date , using ssh to connect into server and run the command there works with escaping e.g

```
ssh name@server.com 'date +"Today is %A"'
```

Comment: this is too broad.  what language are you using?

Comment: just typing this into terminal using linux (Mint)

Comment: This

date +"Today is %A"

gives me "Today is Thursday". Does that work?

Comment: You are comparing two different things...date command syntax "\" is not doing any escaping.. use echo command echo "Today is \%A" you will get what you expect as per your understanding

Comment: The OP hasn't mentioned what shell this is, or how this is being typed.  This risks being down voted.

Comment: i have updated question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Escaping a special character is generally in the shell.  For instance, in bash I get:

```
Today is \Wednesday
```

That's because the backslash here is being passed to the date command which is not seeing it as a special character and thus is just printing it out.

At the bash prompt typing:

```
echo $efs
```

returns a blank line as there is no variable called efs set.  However if I type:

```
echo \$efs
```

I get:

```
$efs
```

Which means the special meaning of the dollar sign defining a variable name is taken away and the shell just printed the string out as is.

Comment: and how could i get outpud "Today is %A " inside date? It can be ridiculous to do but i would like to understand how things work

Comment: Well, you wouldn't.  The date command returns the date in various formats.  See "man date" (How civil these days.  I used to get a gruff RTFM! shouted at me).  Anyway to get what you want you would build a string by combining echo'd strings with date output, that's the power of the shell, combining commands to basically create a new one.  Enjoy your quest for knowledge!

Answer (score 0):

In the OP's posting, the double quotes are escaping their contents, namely the backslash AND percent.

I go for the KISS rule with such things:

```
    "Today is `date +%A`"
```

where the backquotes get the response of the `date` command after passing it to the shell and `+%A` tells `date` how to format it's output.

Answer (score 0):

In date command the backslash does not escape the special meaning of the %.

If you want print the %A in date command, you can use the following.

$ date +"%%A"
%A